# ESRI JavaScript setRequestPreCallback is partially working

Tags: javascript, request, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have an api sitting in front of AGS that requires it's own authentication. I am using setRequestPreCallback as stated by the [ESRI docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.request-amd.html).

In the image below, you can see that the first 2 requests are returning 200. The first request is [CORS Preflight](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0) and the second request is the JS api getting the json info from the MapServer.

[image]

The second request uses the function I have set in setRequestPreCallback(...) to properly set a header value with the token. However, whenever an image is requested from the MapServer (via export), the function I have in setRequestPreCallback is not called and the token is not set, leaving me with a bunch of 401 Unauthorized requests.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure requests to export don't go through esriRequest.

You may be able to append the token by creating a custom dynamic map service layer and overriding `getImageUrl()`. See:

https://gist.github.com/tomwayson/8727474